Why did Tokaku kill Haru?
So I am wondering why Tokaku killed Haru in episode 12. As they were friends, if you could say that, and Tokaku protected Haru, why kill her? And then sob over her dead body, like for real sobbed. Why kill someone you did not want to kill? (Don't worry, Haru lives because of her iron rib, which the knife hit) 

if i recall it was for Tokaku to prove to herself that her feelings for Haru weren't the result of Haru's Queen Bee ability as there was no way for Haru to prove wether or not her ability had affected Tokaku

Oh right, I forgot that bit. Thanks!
